# How to add widget in layout if there is available place for it? Otherwise not to add

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qwidget

In my program I must show information (MarketWidgets with different size) divided in some pages (MarketWidgetsList that hold list of MarketWidgets). My first approach was to add widgets while there is available place for that widget, and if there isn't place another page must be created and add widget to that page. Is it an acceptable approach? To get widget's size I'm using `QWidget::sizeHint()` because the widget still isn't painted, but it seems not correct. Can sizeHint return not exact size if I'm using stretch in layout?
Is there a way to add widget in layout if layout can show widget normally otherwise somehow indicate that there is not enough space?

code example

```
bool  Ui::DynamicMarketsWidget::add_group_market_widget(Ui::GroupMarketWidget *dynamic_group_market_widget)
{ 
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_group_market_widget); 
    int tmp_height = dynamic_group_market_widget->sizeHint().height();                                     if(m_available_height > tmp_height) 
    { 
        m_market_layout->addWidget(dynamic_group_market_widget); 
        m_available_height -= tmp_height; 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: How do you detect, that layout has a place? Could you show some code? It is not necessary to share your production code, you may write an SSCCE.

Comment: bool Ui::DynamicMarketsWidget::add_group_market_widget(Ui::GroupMarketWidget *dynamic_group_market_widget)
{
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_group_market_widget);
    int tmp_height = dynamic_group_market_widget->sizeHint().height();
    if(m_available_height > tmp_height)  {
        m_market_layout->addWidget(dynamic_group_market_widget);
        m_available_height -= tmp_height;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: sorry can't format the code. Here dynamic_group_market_widget is the widget that should be added in layout. I'm simply decrement the available height when adding widget. So if m_available_height > tmp_height there is a place for that widget

Comment: You can edit your question and put code there. Btw, `sizeHint` should not be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

The method `sizeHint()` returns the 'optimal' or 'desired' size of a widget. If a widget is assigned to a layout it does not necessarily have this size. The size the widget currently actually has can be obtained by calling the methods `size()`, `width()` or `height()`.

You could try to update your `m_available_height` with this value instead of the value obtained by the size hint method. Just make sure you assign your widget first before reading the size.

You could try something like this:

```
bool  Ui::DynamicMarketsWidget::add_group_market_widget(Ui::GroupMarketWidget *dynamic_group_market_widget)
{ 
    Q_ASSERT(dynamic_group_market_widget); 
    int tmp_height = dynamic_group_market_widget->sizeHint().height();                                     if(m_available_height > tmp_height) 
    { 
        m_market_layout->addWidget(dynamic_group_market_widget); 
        m_available_height -= dynamic_group_market_widget->height(); 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Yes. I think the height a widget actually has is determined also by the layout it is emplaced in (e.g. stretch etc). I added an example, but I'm not sure if this is going to do what you want. Are you stretching your widgets inside the layout? Maybe try without stretch. Because if the elements are stretched they will return their height as is, meaning in the stretched state. Actually I think the way you did it, using the size hint should work. Maybe you could explain in more detail what the problem is.